# Prove absence of memory leaks

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Is there a way to computationally prove that a program doesn't contain memory leaks?

And if there's no way to "prove", is there a way to "gain 99% confidence" in the same statement?

Answer (score 0):

Most of static analysis tools check for memory leak bugs.